# CakePHP 2:4 : Authcomponent not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

There I have two tables

1) aucusers
2) user_types

For use auth component I used bellow code in appcontroller

```
public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler','Paginator'=>array('limit'=>4),'Auth'=>array(
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'aucusers',
        'action' => 'login'
    ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'add'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'add'),
        'authError'=>'You can not access this page!!',
    ));



public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
     parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
          'limit'=>4
    );
```

In model for Hash password I have used

```
     public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In aucusers controller I have add

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

After add

```
$this->Auth->allow()
```

I have made a user.But when I am going to login, it showing me

Invalid username or password, try again.

Comment: A dirty trick to check your password hashing function is setup correctly - in core.php set debug to 2 then when you attempt to login (and it fails) view the hash it used in the SQL dump. Compare this to the hash in the database. Is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to define which hashing method you are using.

From http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```